# Performance issues with select query for a large CSV file

Tags: vba, excel, vb6

I'm trying to search for data in a very large CSV file (one million records) using `ADO SELECT` query and I have a few `WHERE` clauses in that query.

I cannot transfer this data to any DB (MySql or SQL Server or MS Access) because it is generated daily and I can't transfer it daily to the DB.

I do not have any row id in this .csv file. If there is a row id generated for every .csv by default then please let me know.

Here is the CSV file data sample (first field is date, second is time, third is a value):

```
CSV FILE SAMPLE DATA
====================
20130714,170056,1.30764
20130714,170122,1.30743
20130714,170132,1.30744
20130714,170205,1.30743
20130714,170214,1.30744
20130714,170216,1.30743
20130714,170244,1.30744
20130714,170325,1.30744
20130714,170325,1.30743
20130714,170325,1.30743
20130714,170325,1.30742
20130714,170504,1.30741
20130714,170519,1.30741
20130714,170519,1.30739
20130714,170522,1.30739
20130714,170522,1.30732
20130714,170522,1.30722
```

All the CSV records are in order by date and time.

I'm using ADO connection from Excel to CSV file with this source code:

```
strsql = "SELECT * FROM " & sItem & ".csv WHERE F3>=" & trigPrice & " AND (F1 in (SELECT distinct TOP " & trigWin & "  f1 FROM " & sItem & ".csv WHERE (F1>=" & sDay & ")) AND f2>=" & sTime & ")"
Set rs = cn.Execute(strsql)
```

This one query takes about 10 minutes to execute. How do I reduce the execution time?

Comment: Speed could be affected by the "In (SELECT xxx" statement.  Is there anyway you can write the query without using a subquery?  Based on this subquery, it looks like you could just put the sDay and sTime parameters in the main query, and with a little bit of work perhaps the trigWin as well.

Comment: As is, your SQL statement basically says "Give me all records where the price is above x value, and the date is on or after y# dates where something happened after z date and p time."  So, if you put in, as an example, '20130714' and '170522', ALL of the rows above are returned.  Is this what you want?

Comment: I have used select * because i want all the three values of a row as a result set. This query only returns 3 values of a particular row.

Is there a faster way than doing a sub-query? I had to first find the top 3 distinct available dates in the csv after a particular date and then i have to query in those 3 dates data, thats why i have used sub-query, if you know any faster way of doing it then plz send the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that database queries can be fast is that the data is already indexed - that is, it will have quick lookups on some of the fields.  When you run a "query" on raw CSV files, the ADO engine must first parse the text into records into a set of records, then search through them row by row to find records that match your search criteria.  If you are planning on doing much more than a few queries on the data, you might as well import it into an indexed database table and avoid the duplication of parsing the CSV multiple times.

**UPDATE**

To import the CSV file from VBA, you can use the ['DoCmd.TransferText' function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835958.aspx).  For example, to import a CSV file to a table (with the correct layout) called "tblData" and from a comma seperated CSV with headers, you could do the following:

```
DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , "tblData", "C:\Path\OF\THE.csv", True
```

This is the same method used by the Access Import Wizard.

Comment: I agree.  It is a simple enough matter to import the text file into a temporary Jet MDB created on the fly, add any required indexes through SQL DML, do your queries, and when finished throw the MDB away.

Comment: do you think it will be faster to insert 1 million records in an mdb file first and then query them...because i have to run at least 40 queries. My data already has a unique id...

Look at the CSV data i have attached with question. The first field contains a date value which is in sequence and unique

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are doing.  And I am sure your date is not unique because 1 million unique dates seems pretty implausible.  I created a test case with 1 million records (1000 unique dates and 1000 unique times within each date) and what I get is:  query CSV text took 7.41 seconds, query MDB with imported data took 2.43 seconds.

Comment: BTW: Creating the new MDB and importing 1 million records of text and indexing all 3 fields took 9.2 seconds.

Comment: @user3143422 Because you have to run 40+ queries, it is faster to import the data into an Access database first. As Bob77 points out, the initial import and indexing takes a little extra time (9.2 seconds in his case) but since each query would take much less time, the total time would be reduced.

Comment: I'm still wondering what was taking 10 minutes.  Perhaps there was an error in the SQL statement.

Comment: If I go for the Access DB option. Then everytime user will run the macro, the system needs to import 7 million rows from CSV into ACCESS DB. I have tried this option and just the migration from CSV to MDB took more than 30 minutes. Is there any solution to quickly transfer CSV data into MDB file which will taken only 4-5 minutes.

Comment: What If I import all 3 fields from CSV to MDB and then add a primary key auto number field. Will that help in increasing the speed of queries?

Comment: @user3143422 No. When you "run a query on the CSV", it has load the CSV anyway each time you run a query.  If you load the CSV once into the MDB and index the fields you are planning to query, then the individual queries will run muuuuuch faster. So let's do the math: 30 minutes plus 2-3 minutes for each of the 40 queries you have to run equals a max of 150 minutes (2.5 hrs).  The way you are currently doing it, each of the 40 queries takes 10 minutes which equals 400 minutes (6 hrs 40 mins).  That's at least a 62.5% reduction in the total time.

Comment: @user3143422 I don't understand what you mean by "another way to load the CSV that takes less time".  No matter what database solution you choose, the same amount of work has to be done: the text of the file is parsed row by row.  Each row is split on the commas and delimiting quotation marks are parsed and removed. The individual string fields are loaded into the database structure and a hashing is performed to index them if you indicated so.  Now instead of random characters in a text file, you have a very searchable quick lookup for everything.

Comment: BY this "another way to load the CSV that takes less time" I mean is that when i imported CSV from MS Access Import Wizard in Access 2013 it took 4 minutes to import complete CSV but when i m doing this from a VBA macro it takes 30 minutes to import a CSV into MDB using ADO. So, i m asking for a method which can quickly import CSV into MDB

Comment: @user3143422 Oh! You can use the "Import Wizard" from code instead of ADO. I will update my answer to include an example.

Comment: Blackhawk thanks a lot...do i need to set a reference to use this command or should i just do it as it is and it will run smoothly?